# allow anonymous users to upload in /var/www

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

im fully aware the risk of this setup regarding anonymous upload, but basically, i want anonymous users to upload on my webserver `/var/www`

im using vsftpd btw

I did `mount --bind /var/www /home/upload` and chmod 777 both dir

my vsftpd.conf

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_root=/home/upload
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
```

when i access ftp using filezilla i get this:

```
Response:   500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Please tell me what else did i missed, ive been playing around the configuration, i cant seem to make it work correctly.

Comment: What about umask?

Comment: By the way, I see that you are fully aware the risk of anonymous upload. But are you aware of trying that with a root directory instead of a user directory?

Comment: i have included `anon_mask=077` already. i just wanted to allow anonymous users read/write `/var/www` ive tried both user and root directory and still getting the 500 OOPS

Answer (score 0):

So, maybe try `allow_writeable_chroot=YES` and reload?

Answer (score -1):

1. First check if SElinux is On or Not . 
   we need to set booleans 
   Normally this error is thrown by SElinux 
   check

   ```
    getsebool -a | grep ftp 

    setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access on
   ```

restart the service check once.

connection to the server is always

```
User-->> Firewall -->> Tcp_wrapper -->> SElinux -->> Services -->> File.
```

Comment: there is no SELInux in Ubuntu